# Cannot use Samsung phone from inside virtual machine

Tags: arch-linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, samsung

The same phone will work perfectly fine on a machine running native Windows, but things simply do not work when passing the device through to a virtual machine.

I installed the drivers as usual, but the infamous "This device cannot start. (Code 10)" is reported regardless. I have found little hope in getting this to work during my research.

The virtual machine in question is Windows 7, but I have also tried Windows 8.1. The host operating system is Arch Linux running Virtualbox 5.1. As far as Samsung tools, I tried just installing the drivers directly, using Samsung Kies, and also Samgsung Smart Switch. The phones under test are Samsung Galaxy S6, S6 Edge, S6 Edge+, S7, S7 Edge, etc. I have not yet found a phone that works, so the problem seems to be at a lower level.

I also tried an HTC One device and it does not work either.

Any suggestions? Things to check?

To be clear, the devices are registering with the OS. It is just that the drivers are reporting error and not properly communicating with the devices.

Comment: What VM technology, what configuration, what OS, what version of Windows, what driver versions...  You'll need to update the question with a lot more details!

Comment: @StephenHarris, I updated my question with a bit more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by enabling the `USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller` under USB settings. You must also install the Virtualbox Extension Pack to get the appropriate Virtualbox module to support this setting.

On Arch Linux:

`yaourt -S virtualbox-ext-oracle`

The extension pack is only available in the user repo.